# What should a switch button display: current or future status of feature?

Tags: button, switch-statement, status, display

Lets say, you have an image button at the UI that represents a switchable feature (i.e. tooltips on/off). What should it show according to the status (on/off). I believe, the user is expecting to see a hint for what is going to happen, when he click the button. In this case, the button displays just the opposite of the current status. For example: the two images are lightbulbs, one grey for OFF, one yellow for ON. Now, if the feature status is OFF, the button shows the yellow one, signaling that, if you click on it, the feature will be switched to ON, and vice versa. A colleague said, that this is misleading. If the feature is OFF the button should reflect this, thus displaying a grey lightbulb. I couldn't find any best practice rules for that. Anybody knows some?

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate of another question on ux.stackexchange.com, which is more suited to answering questions like this. Try doing a search there, you'll probably find a good answer :)

Comment: Instead of giving an answer yourself, you advise me to search another side, because you suspect there might this question have been asked before? Really?

Comment: I could answer it, but since I suck at UX, it would be a terrible answer. That's why I pointed you to where the experts are. You could always wait until someone answers it here, but your odds after 2 weeks are effectively 0.